# How did the author derive the distance the particle takes as $\dfrac{h}{\cos\theta}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

On Page 292 of Griffith's Introduction to Electromagnetism (3rd ed.) he mentions that the a basic for of a generator is one in which one pulls a square wire with one side of it in an uniform magnetic field $B$. 
[image]

The charges flowing in segment ab have a vertical velocity $u$ in addition to their horizontal velocity and therefore vertical component $quB$ to the left and horizontal $qvB$ upwards. Therefore the person pulling the wire has to exert a force $f_{\mathrm{pull}}=quB$ to the right. The resultant velocity the particle actually travels is then $w$. Griffiths then states that the distance traveled by the particle is $\dfrac{h}{\cos\theta}$.

Even with both figures that he provides, I'm having a hard time deriving how he got the distance, can anyone tell me how he got that result?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A particle travelling with vertical velocity $u$ distance $h = u \cdot \Delta t$ in the reference frame of the rectangular loop, which is moving horizontally with velocity $v$,
has velocity $w$ (Galilean transformation) in the reference frame of the lab.
In the frame of lab it's travelling the distance $\Delta s = w \cdot \Delta t = h / \cos\theta$, because $\cos\theta = u / w$. It should be obvious, shouldn't it?